error is : ValidationError: Listing validation failed: image: Cast to string failed for value "{ filename: 'listingimage',url :"...." }
while connectiong my database with index.js there is a validation error
ValidationError: Listing validation failed: image: Cast to string failed for value "{
filename: 'listingimage',
url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552733407-5d5c46c3bb3b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fHRyYXZlbHxlbnwwfHwwfHx8MA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60'
}"
index.js file is:-
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const initData = require("./data.js");
const Listing = require("../models/listing.js");
const mongo_url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/WanderLust';//url to conect to mongo database
main().then(()=>{
    console.log("connected to wanderlust");
}).catch((e)=>{
    console.log(e); 
})
async function main(){
    await mongoose.connect(mongo_url);
};


const initDb = async ()=>{
    await Listing.deleteMany({});
    await Listing.insertMany(initData.data);
    console.log("data was initalized");
}

initDb();

data.js file is:-
const sampleListings = [
    {
      title: "Cozy Beachfront Cottage",
      description:
        "Escape to this charming beachfront cottage for a relaxing getaway. Enjoy stunning ocean views and easy access to the beach.",
      image: {
        filename: "listingimage",
        url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552733407-5d5c46c3bb3b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fHRyYXZlbHxlbnwwfHwwfHx8MA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60",
      },
      price: 1500,
      location: "Malibu",
      country: "United States",
    },
    {
      title: "Modern Loft in Downtown",
      description:
        "Stay in the heart of the city in this stylish loft apartment. Perfect for urban explorers!",
      image: {
        filename: "listingimage",
        url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501785888041-af3ef285b470?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTh8fHRyYXZlbHxlbnwwfHwwfHx8MA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60",
      },
      price: 1200,
      location: "New York City",
      country: "United States",
    },
    {
      title: "Mountain Retreat",
      description:
        "Unplug and unwind in this peaceful mountain cabin. Surrounded by nature, it's a perfect place to recharge.",
      image: {
        filename: "listingimage",
        url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571896349842-33c89424de2d?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8N3x8aG90ZWxzfGVufDB8fDB8fHww&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60",
      },
      price: 1000,
      location: "Aspen",
      country: "United States",
    },
    {
      title: "Historic Villa in Tuscany",
      description:
        "Experience the charm of Tuscany in this beautifully restored villa. Explore the rolling hills and vineyards.",
      image: {
        filename: "listingimage",
        url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566073771259-6a8506099945?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8aG90ZWxzfGVufDB8fDB8fHww&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60",
      },
      price: 2500,
      location: "Florence",
      country: "Italy",
    },
    {
      title: "Secluded Treehouse Getaway",
      description:
        "Live among the treetops in this unique treehouse retreat. A true nature lover's paradise.",
      image: {
        filename: "listingimage",
        url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520250497591-112f2f40a3f4?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTV8fGhvdGVsc3xlbnwwfHwwfHx8MA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60",
      },
      price: 800,
      location: "Portland",
      country: "United States",
    }];
module.exports = { data: sampleListings };
    ````

trying to connect my database with my app, but there is a validation error


Check in your db schema for image
